# Is possible to have two subqueries in a from clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm writing this query that has to count two types of data from the same table, but with different properties.

I've already tried to add "AND" and "," between the subqueries, but it doesn't work in these ways.

```
SELECT COUNT(sb1.prop) AS PROP1, COUNT(sb2.prop) AS PROP2
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING%') AS sb1
      AND/,/WHATEVER WORKS
     (SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE%') AS sb2
```

I need to count how many records have the prop like **SOMETHING** and **SOMETHING ELSE**, how can I do it with two subqueries in a single query from clause? I have errors like "*arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric*"

Comment: Yes.  The operator that works in the `FROM` clause is `JOIN` and its variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *appear* to be describing is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(sb1.prop) AS PROP1,
       COUNT(sb2.prop) AS PROP2
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING%') AS sb1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE%') AS sb2;
```

This, however, won't return the results you are after (both `PROP1` and `PROP2` will have the same value). What the above is is effectively the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PROP1,
       COUNT(*) AS PROP2
FROM TABLE t1
     CROSS JOIN TABLE t2
WHERE t1.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
  AND t2.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE%';
```

You could solve this by performing the aggregation in the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING%') AS PROP1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE t WHERE t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE%') AS PROP2;
```

Considering, however, that these are the same table, you would be better off using a condition aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING%' THEN 1 END) AS PROP1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.prop LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE%' THEN 1 END) AS PROP2
FROM TABLE t;
```

Comment: Thanks for these examples, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use conditional aggregation here:

```
select
    sum(case when prop like '%SOMETHING%' then 1 end) sb1,
    sum(case when prop like '%SOMETHING ELSE%' then 1 end) sb2
from mytable
```

Note: with this current setup, things that match `'%SOMETHING%'` will be counted once in each `sum()` (but I can only imagine that this is hypotetical data and filter).